# How To Signal End Of Data Without Closing NetworkStream in C#

Tags: c#, .net

I have a client application that serializes a object and sends it to a server application. The server should deserialize the object, make changes to it, then serialize it and send it back.

Server Code:

```
TcpClient client = server.AcceptTcpClient();
using(NetworkStream stream = client.GetStream())
{
    using(StreamReader streamReader = new StreamReader(stream))
    {
       string xmlData = streamReader.ReadToEnd();
    }
}
```

The ReadToEnd doesn't return unless the client closes the stream. But if the client closes the stream, I can't send a response.

Is there a better way to do this?

Comment: By the way, be aware that `StreamReader.Dispose` (which will be called when you're done reading) will close the underlying stream. Whatever your final solution, you'll have to avoid closing the `StreamReader` until after you've sent the response.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

**You can signal "end of data" by closing only your half of the duplex TCP connection**. This is accomplished with [`Socket.Disconnect`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.sockets.socket.disconnect.aspx).

See how it works with this example, which I kept similar to yours. The client sends the data and then calls `Disconnect`; this allows `ReadToEnd` to return *while still keeping the server's half of the connection open*. The server then sends a response and also disconnects, after which both parties can `Close` their end of the connection to tear it down.

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    Action clientCode = () =>
        {
            var buffer = new byte[100];
            var clientSocket = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork,
                                          SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp);
            clientSocket.Connect(IPAddress.Loopback, 6690);
            clientSocket.Send(buffer);
            clientSocket.Disconnect(false);
            Console.WriteLine("Client: message sent and socket disconnected.");
            while (true) {
                var bytesRead = clientSocket.Receive(buffer);
                if (bytesRead == 0) {
                    break;
                }

                Console.WriteLine("Client: read " + bytesRead + " bytes.");
            }

            clientSocket.Dispose();
        };

    var server = new TcpListener(IPAddress.Loopback, 6690);
    var thread = new Thread(new ThreadStart(clientCode));
    server.Start();
    thread.Start();
    var client = server.AcceptTcpClient();

    using(NetworkStream stream = client.GetStream()) {
        using(StreamReader streamReader = new StreamReader(stream))
        {
            var data = streamReader.ReadToEnd();
            Console.WriteLine("Server: read " + data.Length + " bytes.");

            // Since we 're here we know that the client has disconnected.
            // Send the response before StreamReader is disposed, because
            // that will cause the socket itself to be closed as well!
            Thread.Sleep(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1));
            Console.WriteLine("Server: sending response.");
            stream.Write(new byte[10], 0, 10);
            Console.WriteLine("Server: closing socket.");
        }
    }

    server.Stop();
    Console.WriteLine("Server: waiting for client thread to complete.");
    thread.Join();


    return;
}
```

Comment: I had the same problem but I didn't want to switch from TcpClient/NetworkStream to creating my own Socket directly.  Apparently there's a TcpClient.Client Socket on which I can call Disconnect().  According to the docs there's also a NetworkStream.Socket, but in real life it doesn't seem to be there.  Hopeful this works.

Comment: Nope, that didn't work.  In practice, if I do the Disconnect, then the client can't read from the stream afterword.

Comment: @skiphoppy not sure why your attempts don't work, but this exact code works fine for me. Perhaps you are doing something a little bit differently?

Comment: Thanks man, you saved my day! That disconnect command is really the trigger to send the message

Answer (score 4):

You could use a higher level framework like WCF, or if you are hell-bent on managing your own streams, then don't use ReadToEnd()- use ReadLine() (and have the client send messages as lines), or use Read() and have a special character (a [sentinel](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sentinel_value)) represent the end of a message.

Comment: The client is running on the compact framework. No support for WCF tcp, just http. Tried readline, but it hangs on the last call unless I close the stream. I hate to add a sentinel, it's more code on both sides and will be tricky since I'm transmitting base 64 encoded data. But if that's the only way, then that's what I needed to know.

Comment: @Ben: Does it still hang if the client writes an extra newline after the last line is written?

Comment: I'd have to try it to be sure, but I bet it would. The readline will only return null if it reaches the end of the stream.

Comment: @Ben: I was thinking of using the blank line as a sentinel value.

Comment: @JimMischel Yes, this works. It's not the answer to my question, but it's what I'm going to use.