# Get Content of a http request

Tags: c#, multithreading, sockets, .net-2.0

i am trying to get the content of http request...my program is using threads and sockets to comunicate to a access terminal..
i ne

this is the request sent from the terminal:

`POST /iclock/devicecmd?SN=2182682370001 HTTP/1.1` and the content is 
`ID1&Return=0&CMD=INFO`..

and this is my function to get he full content of http request:

```
private string GetPedido(NetworkStream stream)
{
string sPedido = "" ;
Byte[] bytesFromStream = new Byte[GlobalFunctionAndVariables.iStreamBufferSize];
while (_tcpClient.Available>0)
{
  stream.Read(bytesFromStream, 0, bytesFromStream.Length);
  //Console.Write("available: {0}\n", _tcpClient.Available);
  sPedido += System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetString(bytesFromStream, 0, bytesFromStream.Length);
}
Console.WriteLine("Terminou, a enviar resultado \n");
```

}

the buffer for now is 32 bytes.
for the moment i am only getting the http header and not the content.

if i want to return the content, do i need to parse the string byte by byte..then find the value of content-length and ask to fecth x more bytes.

is this my only option?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Just curious why, if you're processing HTTP requests, you're not using [HttpListener](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.httplistener(v=vs.110).aspx).

Comment: Have you tried using `StreamReader`? Have a look here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7535901/how-to-signal-end-of-data-without-closing-networkstream-in-c-sharp

Comment: change to stream reader, after the streamreader.readtoend(), i put the thread spleep.still not working , because when passing from the streamreader.readtoend() to the thread.sleep, the client close the socket.

Answer (score 0):

The `Available` property does not what you think it does. Remove its use.

Also, you are not using the return value of `Read`. TCP offers you a stream of bytes. A Read operation can return any amount starting with one byte. You code must handle that case.

You should probably continue reading until the remote side is done sending. You can find out about that by checking the amount of bytes read against zero.

Comment: your idea is to have thi:   while(size= stream.Read(bytesFromStream, 0, bytesFromStream.Length)>0);

Comment: Pretty much, yes. That's the canonical way to do it.

Comment: but stiil i need to check if i already got the message, if the condicao is true, them the terminal closes the socket...

Comment: What does condicao mean? You need to parse the response to extract the content. Why not just use an HTTP library?

Comment: im portuguese..when writing in english sometimes i write words in portuguese, my bad...i meant condition..